# How to load bulk data onto iOS device

Tags: ios

I have to load a lot of data onto an iOS device with 128GB storage, for use by my app. The data is around 2,000 files of around 40Mb each, total is around 80GB - 100Gb.

I control the iOS device and the load machine/program and the local network they're on, and time is not critically important (if it takes a week to load, that's OK). I can format the data as required to facilitate the load.

I've done some iOS programming, but I'm not sure where to start looking for a solution to this. If you can outline the broad approach to use and which iOS docs to read up on, that's all I need.

Hoping for a solution where I can format the data and write the program, plug the iPad in to the Mac and say 'start loading' and come back when it's done.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into Enterprise deployments and MDM servers. But seriously, do your users actually use all that data? I would suspect they don't. In which case you might be better to look into how you can break it up so they can just download what they need and not chew up all the space on their very expensive devices.

Comment: Can you just give me some Example for what reason you need 80GB of data in your app ?

Comment: @drekka The app requires all that data locally.  

"do your users actually use all that data?"  
Yes, they do.  

"not chew up all the space on their very expensive devices."  
The expensive devices are being bought to store all this data :-)  

Contractual constraints prevent me from providing examples of the use. The app requires this data, if it didn't I wouldn't be going to this trouble to load it.

Comment: Whoa. Ok. Well I'm guessing a MDM is what you need. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered that it is possible to load data one device at a time using iTunes, but that isn't a good answer for us.

We added a 'load data' button into the application. When triggered it loads a configuration file from a hard coded local network address, then retrieves all the data files listed in the configuration file using REST GETs from the local server, storing them into the application /Documents directory.

This is a good approach for us; it is secure, allows multiple devices to load data at the same time, and doesn't need any manual file loading : start the app, press 'load', and wait for it to finish.